# libspotify sp_search_type

Tags: libspotify

When executing sp_search_create, there is a parameter for sp_search_type which is defined

```
typedef enum sp_search_type {
  SP_SEARCH_STANDARD  = 0,
  SP_SEARCH_SUGGEST = 1,
} sp_search_type;
```

I don't see any change in the result. Is there a suggested way to handle this differently from a normal search ? For instance if we are implementing auto complete or am I missing something here.

Thanks,